# Side menu in window form in .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

How do I create side menu in .net windows application? Is there any possible way to implement this using MDI or should I use some kind of splitter control? Or if you may know to do it with devexpress control, it would be nice too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean with a side menu but the following 2 codeproject articles discuss creating menus similar to the one in older versions of Outlook if that's the kind you mean?

[Navigation Menu for Windows forms (Outlook bar style)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/NavigationMenu.aspx)
[OutlookBar: A Simplified Outlook Style Sidebar Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/OutlookBar.aspx)